# I have to restart firebug/firefox many times a day. Is it Firebug, or is it me?

Tags: javascript, firebug

After an hour or two of heavy use on the site I'm developing, Firebug develops the following problems:

- Breakpoints get glitchy -- it becomes difficult to add/remove breakpoints. Sometimes I click on a line multiple times, see nothing, move to the console tab and back, and then see my breakpoints again.
- Console stops logging xhr's, or stops logging debug statements.
- Script files become non-viewable.

I'm working with a javascript file which is quite large (over 10k lines). I don't think this is a memory leak issue with my own code. I'm refreshing the page all the time. Looks like an issue on the Firebug side. Is my logic sound? Is there anything I can do to get firebug to behave better? Or do I just need to restart firefox every hour?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind Firefox while wonderful has always had many issues with handling memory. You should take a look at your task manager to see Firefox's memory footprint. Additionally I'd break up that JS file if you could into smaller chunks (for many reasons aside of this as well) to be better readable and work with the segments. Finally turn off plugins your not using or that may conflict with Friebug if your not using them.

Comment: I _edit_ the file in little chunks, but then roll everything into one big file as part of a build script. I've been pretty happy with this workflow. I'd like to hear your "many reasons aside of this". When you say "to be better readable", do you mean easier to edit, or easier for firebug to handle?

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours using Firebug without restart Firefox and never crashed, try a clean profile, install on it only Firebug and check if all works fine.

I use a separated development profile with Firebug and other dev oriented extensions installed.

How to configure a profile is described in many sites, on my [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/dafizilla/index.php?title=Misc:mkprofile) you find a brief description

Comment: Great situation where a VM would come in handy, fire up a new VM and you can test away without doing anything to your current desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problems! i think it is partially to do with the massive JS files.  I just re-start firefox every once and a while. no big deal.

Comment: Chromium browser has built in developer tools that are quite comparable to firebug and in my experience I think better.  I have not been using firefox for awhile now and never looked back.  Chromium is also better with memory management.  :-)